# An Excel formula for number of merged cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a formula in Microsoft Excel that takes a reference to a cell as argument and returns the number of cells merged into one? For example, if I merged 3 cells, the formula returns 3 for that cell; if I merged 2 × 4 cells area, the formula returns 8, and so on…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this tiny **UDF** (User Defined Function):

```
Public Function MergeSize(r As Range) As Long
    MergeSize = r(1).MergeArea.Cells.Count
End Function
```

If the UDF returns **1,** the cell stands alone!

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=MergeSize(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 2):

Excel does not have such a function built-in but it would be easy enough to write one.

```
Function mergedcells(rng As Range) As Integer
    mergedcells = rng.MergeArea.Cells.Count
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the offset function can help in a situation if you have data in the column to the left (or below) the this formula counts the number of populated cells a set distance away from the merged cells.

Try the following
=COUNTA(OFFSET('[merged cell range],0,-1))

the -1 is moving the count to one column to the left
if there was data was below the ending would be ,1,0)

if there are only blanks cells around then try the formula

=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET('[merged cell range],0,-1))

if there is mix of empty and populated cells add the formulas together

Comment: Derek, your comment is not that helpful.  I am new and trying to give good advice.  Maybe if you could be helpful in showing what and how it could be improved maybe I could edit and may more pretty.  But a comment like you have made does not give any guidance or clarity

Comment: It was flagged as low quality.  I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: your name is person  who made the comment
"Can you please edit this to be formatted better? "